# Error using DbContextBaseClass in EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, reverse, poco

Error when using a DbContextBaseClass that does not implement a constructor,is there any documentation,Example or Demo on how to use DbContextBaseClass in the template setting to make ASP.NET Identity works ?

i used the guide in the comment:

```
DbContextBaseClass = "DbContext";   // Specify what the base class is for your DbContext. For ASP.NET Identity use "IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>"
```

but i always end up with two a compile errors :

> 1- The type or namespace name 'IdentityDbContext' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 2- The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUser' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Apparently someone else is having the same issue :
[Link Here](https://efreversepoco.codeplex.com/workitem/95)

Answer (score 0):

As the ASP.NET identity already includes all the entity framework code within your project, there is no need to reverse engineer it.

I would instead use the Reverse POCO generator to reverse engineer all your own tables, and add a filter to exclude the ASP.NET identity tables alone.

```
TableFilterExclude = new Regex("^__MigrationHistory$|^AspNetRoles$|^AspNetUserClaims$|^AspNetUserLogins$|^AspNetUserRoles$|^AspNetUsers$");
```